# Simple Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a mod rewrite to simply turn these links:

```
/index.php?page=home
/?page=home
```

into

```
/home
```

Can someone show me how this is done? While we're on the subject, are there any good resources to read up on mod rewrite? My biggest struggle so far is that I don't see any way of debugging it; things either work or they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this. This one applies the rule to any non-existent file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**Edit:** You may have to add `RewriteEngine on` at the top, and this goes in `.htaccess` in your web document root. All of this, of course, depends on whether use of htaccess (mod_rewrite) is allowed by your web host and whether the rule override file should be named .htaccess. Both are pretty common though, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I needed, what do you mean "applies the rule to any non-existent file" though?

Comment: Sure! The `RewriteRule` line only gets applied if the request doesn't match a file on the filesystem (line 1) or a directory on the filesystem (line 2). In other words, this still lets you serve any file that actually exists and passes everything else to index.php

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, you want your end users to enter `example.com/home` and have that rewritten in to `/index.php?home`?

```
RewriteEngine On
# /home or / get redirected...
RewriteRule ^(home)?$ /index.php?page=home [L,QSA]
```

To debug, you can enable the `RewriteLog`.  However, as suggested in the comments it should be used for debugging only.  It is best to disable it or set the level very low in production.

```
RewriteLog "/path/to/logs/rewrite.log"
# Increase the log level (default 0, >4 gets pretty verbose) 
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: Small side note -- `RewriteLogLevel 3` is too low for a serious rewrite debugging -- it will just give you an overview of what is going on without going into details. To see the details use Level 9 -- it much more verbose.

Comment: I would add a serious warning to this answer about the RewriteLog, because it can become a resource hog if you 'forget' about it and it really shouldn't be on on higher levels for long periods of times since that file will become gigabytes bigger fast...

Comment: @sg3s Agreed - I added a note about that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule .*\?page=(\w+)$ /$1/ [NC]
```

Should do the trick but maybe you could be more specific in which cases need to work?

Heres a website you can read up on htaccess

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you. So there's no need for RewriteCond in this case?

Comment: Re-reading your question after the edit I realise this is not what you want to do... For pretty urls check out Matts answer. The website I gave is still a nice resource though :)