# Redirect all traffic to index.php using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache

I'm trying to build a url shortener, and I want to be able to take any characters immediately after the domain and have them passed as a variable url. So for example

- http://google.com/asdf

would become

- http://www.google.com/?url=asdf.

Here's what I have for mod_rewrite right now, but I keep getting a 400 Bad Request:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for the actual error reason. Otherwise set up the `RewriteLog`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Mod Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093190/simple-mod-rewrite)

Comment: -1: More debugging required; see @mario's comment.

Comment: Before all is agood idea add the RewriteBase directive. Second, the server allow mod_rewrite ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try replacing `^(.*)` with `^(.*)$`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Edit: Try replacing `index.php` with `/index.php`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but still get the 400 Bad Request. Looking through the logs now, but I can't seem to find anything worth while

Comment: @bswinnerton: Try adding a `/` before `index.php`.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, so I no longer get the error anymore, but it doesn't redirect to url=asdf when I type in /asdf =/

Comment: @bswinnerton: What do mean by "when I type in /asdf"?  What's the URL you're trying to load?

Comment: For example if I type in google.com/asdf it just goes back to google.com instead of google.com/?url=asdf

Comment: Building on that, I think that this might have something to do with my source code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

ByTheWay don't forget to enable mod rewrite,in apache on ubuntu

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart apache2

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

edit: it is an old question that helped me but I lost hours testing my apache2.conf file on one side and .htaccess file on the other side and still no light.

Answer (score 2):

To rewrite all requests to `/index.php` ,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

The RewriteCondition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$` is important as it excludes the rewrite destination we are rewriting to and prevents infinite looping error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without using using `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Those two `RewriteCond` lines are to make sure that files and folders that really exist don't get rewritten.  For example `http://example.com/images/logo.png` won't get rewritten if that image exists.

Comment: @Rocket Good to know for future reference. I was just working with the information I was given.

Answer (score 0):

Check under Apache modules and make sure that rewrite-module is enabled. I had a similar issue and it was resolved by enabling the rewrite-module.

Comment: what use does it have to answer a super old question **that already has been answered**?

Comment: Actually this solved my problem after 2 hours of searching, I'm not a PHP programmer but I use it some times on my website.

Answer (score 0):

in the framework folder create an .htaccess file with the following contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

then in the framework/public folder create an .htaccess file with the contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

by adding the .htaccess file as above we can make the URL on the website more user-friendly.
For example if we write a URL like

```
http://google.com/asdf
```

will be converted to

```
http://google.com?url=asdf
```

for test purposes, we create a php index.php file in a public folder with the following content

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['url'];
?>
```

if when run in a browser using the URL above the result is 404 not found, most likely mod_rewrite has not been enabled as in step 1. if the result is 500 Internal Server Error, there may be an error in writing .htaccess