# Redirect calls made to apache through a php

Tags: php, tomcat, apache2

(apache here I refer to apache2 webserver)
I have a setup where in my jsp calls to tomcat are routed by apache using mod_jk. Both servers reside on the same machine. I want to do away with the mod_jk connector, instead the calls coming to apache is served by making a curl call to the localhost tomcat server.

The problem is the queries comming are of the type 'something/something.jsp' or 'anything/anything.jsp'. I want all this requests coming to apache be serviced by a common php code, which will do the corresponding curl call and return the response. The reason I am using the php connector is for some specific logging purposes.

Completely new to the apache world so any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: Could you clarify the flow of controls? For example the request starts at a JSP on tomcat which you then route to Apache through mod_Jk and then the request is handled by a PHP script? You want to get rid of mod_jk and make it so the request comes to PHP first which will then use curl to call the apache tomcat jsp?

Comment: Hi Usman, infact its the other way round. Requests come to apache first and then this request is sent to tomcat via modjk. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: So your goal is to have requests hit Apache and then instead of mod_jk use a curl call to call your JSP pages?

Comment: Yes,exactly what I am looking for !

Comment: I see. I added some stuff about Mod_rewrite. Perhaps all you need is a package to make Apache accept any request pattern as your "logger.php". I believe that is what Mod_rewrite is for and a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [Mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) so that apache accepts all requests types as just another call to `Logger.php` instead of `/something/something.jsp`. And pass the original request to the php page which from their can make the curl request.

Here is an example of someone trying to route all requests to a particular php page. A bit similar to your scenario but he wants the requests to be changed to query string parameters ->
[Redirect all traffic to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595964/redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-using-mod-rewrite)

**Note:** URL processing is child's play in Tomcat. I think it would be a lot easier to have your requests come directly to a tomcat filter which can call your PHP page and then send the request onto the designated JSP page. If you are allowed to reverse your architecture.