# Capture URLs after slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

`http://domain.com?keyword=value`

...is easy to capture as its a simple GET request, however, I'd like to capture values that I pass directly after the `/` like so:

`http://domain.com/value`

And I can fetch those values like so:

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "http://www.domain.com/value", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // value
```

... however, the URL results in a `404` because its looking for a directory named `value` which is obviously  non-existing.

Comment: It is not clear for me what exactly you try to achieve, because php here works as you want. Probably url rewriting?

Comment: @alphawow Exactly, URL rewriting

Comment: All requests to index page maybe?

Comment: You can redirect any URL to a certain file, e.g. router.php and then you can read the URL with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595964/redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-using-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple URL rewrite will do it. And you can remove that ugly regex.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Explanation:**

`RewriteEngine on` - sets the rewrite engine on
`RewriteBase /` - / means the root of your project/website and is everything after the domain in this case
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` - is not an actual file
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` - is not an actual directory
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` - send everything after the domain to url key GET global variable

Now you can get the url with `$_GET['url']`. Of course, you can change the key to that GET.

Comment: If `domain.com/somevalue` is a folder, it will display that folder (if is not blocked from apache level). However, the 404 page can be made from your php code.

Comment: wow, an elegant solution! :)