# How to mod_rewrite so URL redirects other way around?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file where when a user signs up on my site, they'll be redirected to `example.com/profiles/[username]` . The ugly URL is `example.com/profiles/?username=john` where john can be any name. Whenever, the user searches for let's say `example.com/profiles/[username]` a 404 gets displayed, so instead I want this friendly URL to redirect to an ugly one so their profile can be displayed. So I want `example.com/profiles/john` to be redirected to `example.com/profiles/?username=john` internally.

Here's my .htaccess conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profiles/\?username=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profiles/%1? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^profiles/([\w-]+)/?$ /profiles/?username=$1 [L]
```

These conditions successfully remove the `?username=john` part of the URL, how do I make it so it's the other way around? So when someone searches for `example.com/profiles/john` it gets redirected to `example.com/profiles/?username=john` internally so the page gets successfully displayed?

Comment: you say "internally". Do you want the browser to still think it's at `example.com/profiles/john` but for some script in the `profiles` directory to receive `username=john` as a `$_GET` key=>value?

Comment: @Terminus With the above rewrite rules, when I go to example.com/profiles/?username=john, it is redirecting the URL to example.com/profiles/john and displaying a 404 error like the page doesn't exist. So my solution to this was if the user types in the friendly URL, they'll be redirected to the ugly URL so the profile could be displayed and the 404 error would be gone. Preferably, I'd love it for the URL in the browser to stay in its friendly state and not change to the ugly one. But the friendly URL is displaying a 404. If that makes sense

Comment: one other question then: do you have a `profiles` directory in your webroot and an `index.php` file in that directory (technically 2 questions but hey)

Comment: imo, just switching your rule to something like the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595964/redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-using-mod-rewrite would benefit you. You can then use the index page to do the stuff you have to do on every page (connect to db, bring in your commonly used functions, etc...) You could then handle the "routing" by including files based on the `url` parameter (which i suggest you change to something not so common)

Comment: @Terminus With this added, i'm just getting a 500 error

Comment: Sorry, what was added?

Comment: @Terminus I added RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115916/discussion-between-terminus-and-bytes).

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/profiles/?username=user` to `/profiles.user` you can use

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profiles/\?username=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profiles.%1? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^profiles\.([^/]+)/?$ /profiles/?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry I meant I want to redirect example.com/profiles/user to example.com/profiles/?username=user

Comment: @Bytes  your orignal rule already rewrites it. what's the problem?

Comment: My original rule rewrites example.com/profiles/?username=user to example.com/profiles/user but I don't want this. I want it to rewrite example.com/profiles/user to this example.com/profiles/?username=user

Comment: Remove the external redirect (first 2 lines) 
leave this

    `RewriteRule ^profiles/([\w-]+)/?$ /profiles/?username=$1 [L]`

Comment: With this nothing is happening. example.com/profiles/john isn't redirecting to example.com/profiles/?username=john it's staying the same and displaying a 404 error