# How do I make a dynamic URL for a 404 xhtml page?

Tags: url, xhtml, http-status-code-404, redirect, web.xml

I have defined a location for the page in the **xml**

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/faces/public/error-page-not-found.xhtml</location>
   </error-page>    
<error-page>
```

but I want the URL to be like below:

```
faces/{variable}/public/error-page-not-found.xhtml
```

where the value of the variable will change according to different situations

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit subjective though in general HTTP errors are handled by the server and most of the time by the scripting language on the server (and occasionally the HTTP server software directly).

In example the Apache HTTP web server software allows for rewrites. So you can request a page at *example.com/123* though there is no "123" file there. In the code that would determine if you would have something that would be available for that request you would also determine if a resource exists for that request; if not then your server scripting code (PHP, ColdFusion, Perl, ASP.NET, etc) would need to return an HTTP 404. The server code would then have a small snippet that you would put in to the body of the code such as the code you have above.

You would not need to redirect to an error page, you would simply respond with the HTTP 404 response and any XML you'd use to notify the visitor that there is nothing there. HTTP server software such as Apache can't really produce code (it can only reference or *rewrite* some file to be used for certain requests).

Generally speaking if you have a website that uses a database you'd do the following...

1. Parse the URL requested so you can determine what the visitor requested.
2. Determine if a resource should be retrieved for that request (e.g. make a query to the database).
3. Once you know whether a resource is available or not you then either show the resource (e.g. a member's profile) or server the HTTP status (401: not signed in at all, 403:, signed in though not authorized where no increase in privileges will grant permission, 404: not found, etc) and display the corresponding content.

I would highly recommend that you read about Apache rewrites and PHP, especially it's `$_SERVER` array (e.g. `<?php print_r($_SERVER);?>`). You'd use Apache to rewrite all requests to a file so even if they request /1, /a, /about, /contact/, etc they all get processed by a single PHP file where you first determine what the requested URL is. There are tons of questions here and elsewhere on the web that will help you really get a good quick jump start on handling all that such as this: [Redirect all traffic to index.php using mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595964/redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-using-mod-rewrite). If you do not know how to setup a local HTTP web server I highly recommend looking in to [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), it's what I started out with years ago. Good luck!