# How to rewrite the my URL like sub domain by using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi this my website http://techiesbadi.tk/

here rewrite the url like this test.techiesbadi.tk as http://techiesbadi.tk/index.php?siteName=test

i used this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?siteName=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.techiesbadi.tk
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?siteName=%1
```

But my problem is when i redirect test.techiesbadi.tk
it gives the This webpage is not available
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Is there any mistake in my code please help me.

You can see my website http://techiesbadi.tk/
here i implemented some mechanism like sub domain creation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Mod Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093190/simple-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Hi Mr. Jojo01 . I edited my question with exact what i need please help me.

Comment: Since you're using Dot.tk if they have an api you could maybe just create a New subdomain. And it's not a very good idea to directly put a link to your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a *good* reason to do this, but it's possible with wildcard DNS.

Currently in your DNS setup you'd have something like:

`techiesbadi.tk.        14273   IN  A   31.220.16.205`

If you add this:

`*.techiesbadi.tk.      14273   IN  A   31.220.16.205`

Hence, all requests to a subdomain of your site will still route. You can parse the subdomain within Apache's rules, PHP, whatever.